# Mac Terminal read each .txt file in folder and write (add) as text to specific file

Tags: macos, terminal, mac, command-line

I have folder with 600+ .txt files. 
Each file has couple lines of short text. 
I want to create another file and write text from all those files to new one. 
Are there some Terminal commands or tools to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This command will take all .txt files combine to a single file.

`cat ~/name_of_folder/*.txt > ~/combined.txt`

Comment: error message: cat: /Users/me/folder/*.txt: No such file or directory

Comment: Open Terminal, write `cat` drag all text files you want to import to the terminal window, write ` > ` drag an empty text file to the Terminal window, press enter in Terminal.